# How to properly display a custom dialog in an adapter

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have a custom adapter in my app, and i launch several activities from there, one of the populated lists in the adapter takes you back to the login screen which works fine, but I decided to add a confirmation dialog before taking the user to the login screen, but I get an error saying `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {  }`

This is what I've implemented so far

**AccountAdapter.java**

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;
        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setClickable(true);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            mCtx = view.getContext();
            title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            icon = view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            switch (getAdapterPosition()){
                case 0:
                    intent =  new Intent(mCtx, SettingsActivity.class);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent =  new Intent(mCtx, ProfileActivity.class);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent =  new Intent(mCtx, ChangePasswordActivity.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    CustomAlertDialog alert = new CustomAlertDialog((Activity)mCtx);//faulty code
                    alert.show();
                    break;
            }
            mCtx.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

**CustomAlertDialog.java**

```
public class CustomAlertDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    public Activity c;
    public Dialog d;
//    public Button yes, no;
    public TextView yes, no;

    public CustomAlertDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog);
        yes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
//        no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
        yes.setOnClickListener(this);
//        no.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_yes:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

**AccountFragment.java** (where I populate the account adapter)

```
private void prepareAccountData() {
//        if (mAdapter == null) {
//            return;
//        }
        AccountModel options = new AccountModel("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings);
        accountList.add(options);
        options = new AccountModel("Update Profile", R.drawable.ic_social_person_outline);
        accountList.add(options);
        options = new AccountModel("Change Password", R.drawable.ic_hardware_security);
        accountList.add(options);
        options = new AccountModel("Logout", R.drawable.ic_action_exit_to_app);
        accountList.add(options);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and this is the code I use for direct logout which works aswell

```
((Activity)mCtx).finish();
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences("key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.apply();
                    intent =  new Intent(mCtx, LoginActivity.class);
```

How can I implement the custom dialog in my adapter?

Comment: Could you attach crash log? and I don't see the code you handle yes in dialog

Comment: I haven't handled yes i dialog yet, just trying to get the dialog working first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has bug you don't init `intent` in case show dialog, you should move logic into `onClick` in your `Dialog`, move this `mCtx.startActivity(intent);` into case

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (getAdapterPosition()){
        case 0:
            mCtx.startActivity(new Intent(mCtx, SettingsActivity.class));
            break;
        case 1:
            mCtx.startActivity(new Intent(mCtx, ProfileActivity.class));
            break;
        case 2:
            mCtx.startActivity(new Intent(mCtx, ChangePasswordActivity.class));
            break;
        default:
            CustomAlertDialog alert = new CustomAlertDialog((Activity)mCtx)
            alert.show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: removing `mCtx.startActivity(intent);` would prevent other activities from starting

Comment: the last code is my question, i need to add it to the dialog yes button

Comment: Yeah, should handle navigate inside your dialog, dismiss when user press `no`

Comment: What error ok we can discuss other question in chat

Comment: please check chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221698/room-for-kennedy-and-cong-hi?highlights=false